# How to delete multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a secondhand sale car database and four tables with relationships. Same column names have relationships.

Tables are:
`Record`: RecID Markname Model...
`Features`: FeatureID Featurename
`Marks`: MarkID Markname
`Carfeature`: CarfeatureID RecID FeatureID

Now, i want to delete a mark from Marks in c#. When i delete a mark, SQL must delete all records who has this mark.

I used a query like that:

```
DELETE from Carfeature 
 where RecID = (select RecID 
 from Record 
 where Mark = (select markname 
                 from Marks 
                where MarkID=@MarkID))";


    string sorgudelmarkfromrecord = "DELETE from Record where Mark=
(select Markname from Marks where MarkID=@MarkID)";

    string sorgudelmark = "DELETE from Marks where MarkID=@MarkID";
```

When i run this, i get an error message like this:

`Subquery` returned **more than 1** value.

This is not permitted when the `subquery` follows `=, !=, <, <= , >, >=` or when the `subquery` is used as an expression.

The statement has been terminated.

So, how can i delete multiple data from a table?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can use this query to remove all CarFeatures for a cerain MarkID:

```
DELETE FROM CarFeature 
WHERE RecID IN (
    select RecID 
    from Record 
    where Markname IN (
        select Markname 
        from Marks 
        where MarkID = @MarkID
    )
)
```

The removal of records and marks is a simpler version of this query, I'll leave the exact SQL up to you.

Comment: +1 for spending more time to format your answer clearly than i did. :)

Comment: Thanks both of you friends. I tried and it worked. I know it is very simple but i am a newbie programmer. i should work harder on SQL queries :) Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

instead of using `where RecID=(...)` use `where RecID in (...)`

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
DELETE from Record r 
where r.Mark in
    (select m.Mark from Marks where r.MarkID=m.MarkID);
```

Note:
markid must be primary key in both tables..

Answer (score 0):

ON DELETE CASCADE on the foreign key?